# Anyone familiar with an implementation of mapbox in bokeh?

Tags: mapbox, bokeh

I'm building a dashboard in bokeh using public health data that includes geo-mapping but would like to explore mapbox as alternative to the tile system I'm using. Can mabox be deployed as a tile_provider? Through a gmap like function? api access? Bokeh 0.12.2 release stated that users can develop custom map visualizations using Mapbox.js but I did not see any example or use case.

Comment: I understood the [patchnotes](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2016/9/6/release-0-12-2/) that integration with 3rd party plugins is now supported so that a 3rd party mapbox plugin is possible, but not that one actually exists currently.

Comment: Thanks, I got a similar response from Mapbox.